# SQL database Vs. Access database when using VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net

Does it matter which Database you decide to use in your VB.net program? If someone could give me a Pros and Cons of maybe performance/ simplicity/ potential that would be great. I know Access fairly well, but if SQL is better I would like to switch over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it matters. If you are talking about a **real system** you should use **SQL Server** without even considering access as an alternative.

MS access is a light database management system oriented to amateurs. It lacks many of the administration tools needed on a real system. Of course, it is a lot easier to setup and learn.

SQL Server is a relational database management system providing professional tools. [SQL Server Management Studio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) is the default graphical tool on which you can administer your SQL Server instance.

Regarding **performance** SQL Server is definetely better. Regarding **simplicity** Access is a lot easier to learn. Regarding **potential** I suppose the SQL server certainly is better.

Perhaps [this post](http://www.expresstechnology.com/support/knowledge-base/46-sql-database-server/103-what-is-the-advantage-of-microsoft-sql-server-over-access) could clarify things for you...

Hope I helped!

Comment: This is everything and more I wanted to know :) Thanks a-lot mate :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your program bro.

let me start with MS ACCESS, MS Access is actually a combination of a rapid development UI tool and file system based relational database (JET). Access is intended for end users. it does not cater multiple users. however, it is easy to deploy and much cheaper especially for small installations.

on the other hand, MS SQL SERVER is a Client-server relational database system, with no UI development tools built in. It is also designed to support more users a lot easier to maintain because of its tools provided. Compared to MS ACCESS, it is more complex and has No built-in UI development tools - You will need another dev platform to build a front-end and (arguably) reporting. In my case, i usually implement Crystal reports as my reporting tool....

In conclusion. It is really your choice on what database you are going to use....if its just a simple application, better use MS ACCESS... but if you are creating an application that caters client server interaction, better use MS SQL SERVER...